# Where to run the command to access private S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Apologies, this is such a rookie question. A report I set up is being run daily and deposited in the customer S3 bucket. I was given the command to run if I wanted to inspect the bucket contents. I want to verify my report is as expected in there, so I'd like to access it. But I have no idea where to actually run the command.

Do I need to install AWS CLI and run it there, is there something I need to install so I can run it from Terminal. The command has the AWS secret key, access key and URL.

Comment: Yep, installing AWS CLI is probably your first step.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to access an object from Amazon S3 on your own computer:

- Download the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)
- Run: `aws configure` and provide your Access Key & Secret Key
- To list a bucket: `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name`
- To download an object: `aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/object-name.txt .`

(That last period means *"to the current directory"*.)